# adehabitatHR, LoCoH Issue with orphan holes

Tags: adehabitathr

I am use adehabitatHR to calculate HR's utilizing the `LoCoH` method.  I am attempting to find the optimal settings, but and having trouble because at a number of settings I am getting the following:

```
y<-LoCoH.k(mastermatrix, k=6, unin="m", unout="m", duplicates="random")
Error in rgeos::createPolygonsComment(oobj) : 
  rgeos_PolyCreateComment: orphaned hole, cannot find containing polygon for hole at index 19
```

I generally understand what this means, however all of the advice for orphan holes and rgeos are in situations where the person is coding the unions themselves rather than using another package that feeds through.

I can get HR's at a number of different settings so I know my data is sufficient, but I want to make sure that I am optimizing my settings.  Any advice as to what factors of my data is causing this would be helpful.

Do I need to do further QAQC on my location data?
Are there possibly settings I am missing?